# Sinon stubbing giving 'is not a function' error

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, sinon, sinon-chai

first time really using sinon and I am having some issues with the mocking library.

All I am trying to do is stub/mock out a function from a `dao` class called `myMethod`. Unfortunatly, I am getting the error: `myMethod is not a function`, which makes me believe I am either putting the `await/async` keywords in the wrong spots of the test or I don't understand sinon stubbing 100%. Here is the code:

```
// index.js
async function doWork(sqlDao, task, from, to) {
  ...
  results = await sqlDao.myMethod(from, to);
  ...
}

module.exports = {
  _doWork: doWork,
  TASK_NAME: TASK_NAME
};
```

```
// index.test.js

const chai = require("chai");
const expect = chai.expect;
const sinon = require("sinon");

const { _doWork, TASK_NAME } = require("./index.js");
const SqlDao = require("./sqlDao.js");

.
.
.

  it("given access_request task then return valid results", async () => {
    const sqlDao = new SqlDao(1, 2, 3, 4);
    const stub = sinon
      .stub(sqlDao, "myMethod")
      .withArgs(sinon.match.any, sinon.match.any)
      .resolves([{ x: 1 }, { x: 2 }]);

    const result = await _doWork(stub, TASK_NAME, new Date(), new Date());
    console.log(result);
  });
```

With error:

```
  1) doWork
       given task_name task then return valid results:
     TypeError: sqlDao.myMethod is not a function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you're passing `stub` to `_doWork` instead of passing `sqlDao`.

A stub isn't the object that you just stubbed. It is still a sinon object that you use to define the behaviour of the stubbed method. When you're done with your tests, you use `stub` to restore stubbed object.

```js
const theAnswer = {
    give: () => 42
};

const stub = sinon.stub(theAnswer, 'give').returns('forty two');

// stubbed
console.log(theAnswer.give());

// restored 
stub.restore();
console.log(theAnswer.give());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sinon.js/7.2.4/sinon.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ug, you are right! Thank you, I think I mixed up calls when I was trying to use it as a `mock`. If you could, could you also give an example as it would be a mock instead of a stub?